# A subspace of the homogeneous Sobolev space $\dot{W}^{1,p}% (\mathbb{R}^{N})$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Given $1\leq p<\infty$, the homogeneous Sobolev space $\dot{W}^{1,p}
(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ is defined as the space of all functions $u\in
L_{\operatorname*{loc}}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ such that the distributional
gradient $\nabla u$ belongs to $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{N};\mathbb{R}^{N})$. This
space is a seminormed space and it can be made into a normed space by
considering the quotient space $\dot{W}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})/\mathbb{R}$.

In
a classical paper "Some problems of vector analysis and generalized
formulations of boundary-value problems for the Navier-Stokes equations"
Ladyzhenskaya and Solonnikov consider the space $\dot{H}^{1,p}%
(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ defined as the closure in $\dot{W}^{1,p}
(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ of the space of functions $u\in
C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ such that $u_{B}=0$ with respect to the
seminorm $\Vert\nabla u\Vert_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})}$, that is,
$$
\dot{H}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{N}):=\overline{\{u\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}%
^{N}):\,u_{B}=0\}}^{\dot{W}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})}.
$$
Here,$$
u_{B}:=\frac{1}{\mathcal{L}^{N}(B)}\int_{B}u\,dx.
$$
The importance of this subspace is that the following Hardy-type inequalities
hold in $\dot{H}^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$, $N\geq2$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}\frac{|u(x)-u_{B}|^{p}}{(1+\Vert x\Vert^{2})^{p/2}}dx\leq
c\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}\Vert\nabla u(x)\Vert^{p}dx
$$
for $p\neq N$ and for some constant $c=c(N,p)>0$, and
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}\frac{|u(x)-u_{B}|^{N}}{(1+\Vert x\Vert^{2}\log^{2}\Vert
x\Vert)^{N/2}}dx\leq c\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}\Vert\nabla u(x)\Vert^{N}dx
$$
for $p=N$ and for some constant $c=c(N)>0$. A sketch of the proof for $p=N$ is
given in the above paper.

I would like to find an example (if it exists) of a function which belongs to
$\dot{W}^{1,N}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ but does not satisfy the above Hardy's
inequality (and so does not belong to $\dot{H}^{1,N}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$).

The standard pathological function in $\dot{W}^{1,N}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ is
$u(x)=\log\log\Vert x\Vert$ for $\Vert x\Vert\geq2$ and anything nice in
$B(0,2)$. Unfortunately the left-hand side of the previous inequality is finite since
$$
\int_{2}^{\infty}r^{N-1}\frac{|\log\log r-u_{B}|^{N}}{(1+r^{2}\log^{2}%
r)^{N/2}}dr\leq c\int_{2}^{\infty}r^{N-1}\frac{|\log\log r|^{N}}{r^{N}\log
^{N}r}dr\leq c\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r\log^{N-\varepsilon}r}dr<\infty.
$$
I cannot think of anything else.